# Borrowed value does not live long enough with a Tokio future

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rust-tokio

I'm trying to write a simple HTTP server using Rust and tokio.

Everything works fine until I want to send the response.

The code is the following:

```
use std::fs;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::net::TcpListener; // 0.1.15
use tokio::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:8080".parse().unwrap();
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).expect("unable to bind TCP listener");

    let incoming = listener.incoming();

    let server = incoming
        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("accept failed = {:?}", e))
        .for_each(|socket| {
            println!(
                "Connection established: from {:?} to {:?}",
                socket.peer_addr(),
                socket.local_addr()
            );
            let bytes = vec![0; 512];
            let processor = tokio::io::read(socket, bytes)
                .and_then(|(socket, bytes, _size)| {
                    println!("Request: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&bytes[..]));
                    let contents = fs::read_to_string("hello.html").unwrap();
                    let response = Arc::new(format!("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n{}", contents));
                    let response = response.clone();
                    tokio::io::write_all(socket, response.as_bytes()).and_then(|_| Ok(()))
                })
                .map_err(|_| ());
            tokio::spawn(processor);
            Ok(())
        });

    tokio::run(server);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `response` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:27:50
   |
27 |                     tokio::io::write_all(socket, response.as_bytes()).and_then(|_| Ok(()))
   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
28 |                 })
   |                 - `response` dropped here while still borrowed
```

How do I have to declare the response to live enough?

Comment: Why don't you just use `into_bytes`,  instead of wrapping with arc and passing the borrowed bytes array ? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d06af32637054e2fbe5ca9f16d60612)

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But I don't understand why wrapping with arc didn't.

Answer (score 1):

### How can you make it work ?

As i pointed in my comment: use `into_bytes`, instead of wrapping with `Arc` and passing the borrowed bytes array.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d06af32637054e2fbe5ca9f16d60612)

---

@David:

> But I don't understand why wrapping with arc didn't.

`Arc` counts reference of inner object:

- it increases the reference when you `clone()`
- it decreases the reference when the **owner** of `Arc` gets dropped.
- it gets dropped from the memory when reference count decreases to **0**

In your case owner of the `Arc`, which is named as `response`. `response` is created in scope and dropped at the end of the same scope. It's ref count was 1 when it was created, it became 0 after dropped. But you've passed a reference of `Arc` inside a `Future` right before it has removed from memory.

Please note that `write_all()` creates a `Future` and that `Future` carries a reference of your `Arc`, which is removed from memory before the `Future`'s execution.

**Note**: `WriteAll` can have ownership of **borrowed** or **moved** value it expects a generic parameter which can be converted to a `slice`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand the difference between Arc and into_bytes(). If I understand correctly, Arc is dropped when going out of scope because it haven't been executed yet. Even if declaring a response2=response.clone(). But using into_bytes() shouldn't work either. It creates a response that is a vector that goes out of scope before the future gets executed. Where is the difference?

Comment: @David Simply with as_bytes `Future`(`WriteAll`) borrows bytes, with `into_bytes` the `Future` takes ownership of bytes. bytes will not be dropped in the scope due to `Future` has ownership, so it guarantees that it will be dropped in `Future` or after it's execution.

Comment: @David also `write_all` expects a generic parameter which can be converted to a slice, so you can use borrowed or moved argument to call `write_all`

Comment: Yes, now it’s clear the difference. Thank you Ömer.