# "borrowed value does not live long enough" when using tokio::spawn with a future with a mutable reference

Tags: asynchronous, rust, reference, rust-tokio, borrow

The following code does not compile bceause the compiler can not assure `hashmap_of_lists` would live long enough. I can not overcome this.

I've tried using `Arc` and `Mutex` but then I had other issues because of the async fashion of `some_func` and using `Mutex` inside.

```rust
use futures; // 0.3.5
use std::collections::HashMap;
use tokio; // 0.2.21

async fn some_func(_some_slice: &mut [String]) {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut hashmap_of_lists = HashMap::<String, Vec<String>>::new();
    let mut join_handles = Vec::new();

    for (_, value) in hashmap_of_lists.iter_mut() {
        let future = some_func(value);
        let join_handle = tokio::task::spawn(future);
        join_handles.push(join_handle);
    }

    futures::future::join_all(join_handles).await;
}
```

I get this error

```
error[E0597]: `hashmap_of_lists` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:23
   |
12 |     for (_, value) in hashmap_of_lists.iter_mut() {
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------
   |                       |
   |                       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                       argument requires that `hashmap_of_lists` is borrowed for `'static`
...
19 | }
   | - `hashmap_of_lists` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: `tokio::task::spawn` requires a `'static` future, but a future that takes a borrowed reference is not `'static`. The esiest solution woult be to use `into_iter()` instead of `iter_mut()` and pass ownership of the lists into your future, but I don't know if that will fit your real code.

Comment: async have their own version of mutex https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.13/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Borrowed value does not live long enough with a Tokio future](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55610608/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Still, I could not manage to overcome this issue. Using a mutex requires an unneeded lock. As for the into_iter, still, I could not satisfy the borrow checker to think that the reference would still point at a valid address.

Comment: rodrigo advice code https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=90e10fd5e6e242f1a3fead68ce81435a

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the problem with your solution is that the value is copied. I've been trying to come with a solution without a copy. :/

Comment: If you want to avoid passing `Vec<String>` to `some_func()`, then maybe you can wrap it inside a `Box`, i.e. `Box<Vec<String>>`. However, passing `Vec` to a function doesn't cost much, since the content of `Vec` is heap-allocated. It's a fixed 24 bytes on my machine, while `Box` is 8 bytes.